# Angular2 - access the AbstractControl instance in validation directive

Tags: forms, validation, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have to trigger validation from the inside of a validator directive.

Here is the directive I have. It works as expected. However I want it to trigger the validation process when the validator function changes. I.e. when its input variable `maxDate` changes.

How could I do this ?

**If I could access the AbstractControl instance in the constructor I could easily do this. I can't think of a way to do it, however.**

```
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


function parseDate(date: string):any {  
  var pattern = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/;
  if (date) {
    var replaced = date.search(pattern) >= 0;    
    return replaced ? new Date(date.replace(pattern,'$3-$1-$2')) : null;
  }

  return date;
}


export function maxDateValidator(maxDateObj): ValidatorFn {
  return (control:AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {    
    const val = control.value;

    let date = parseDate(val);
    let maxDate = parseDate(maxDateObj.max);    

    if (date && maxDate && date > maxDate) {
      return {
        maxDateExceeded: true
      };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

...

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[maxDate]',  
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: maxDateDirective, multi: true}]  
})
export class maxDateDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {
  @Input() maxDate: string;

  private valFn = Validators.nullValidator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const change = changes['maxDate'];
    if (change) {
      const val: string  = change.currentValue;      
      this.valFn = maxDateValidator(val);
    }
    else {
      this.valFn = Validators.nullValidator;
    }
    //This is where I want to trigger the validation again.
  }

  validate(control): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.valFn(control);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="deathDateVal">

  <input class="form-control"          
          type="text"
          tabindex="1"
          [maxDate]="deathDateVal"
          name="will_date"
          [textMask]="{pipe: datePipe, mask: dateMask,  keepCharPositions: true}"
          ngModel
          #willDate="ngModel">
```

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I want to retrigger the validation when validation parameters change. I.e `maxDate`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. `ngOnChanges` is invoked whenever any input changes, so whenever `maxDate` changes. Your code should be working.

Comment: Yes, it does. The validation process is not triggered with it, however. `willDate.errors` remains the same.

Comment: Just from looking at the code, I don't see why. Besides, your code is almost verbatim that of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#custom-validation so it should be working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I've just come up with:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[maxDate]',  
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: maxDateDirective, multi: true}]  
})
export class maxDateDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {
  @Input() maxDate: string;

  private valFn = Validators.nullValidator;
  private control:AbstractControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const change = changes['maxDate'];
    if (change) {
      const val: string  = change.currentValue;      
      this.valFn = maxDateValidator(val);
    }
    else {
      this.valFn = Validators.nullValidator;
    }

    if (this.control) {
      this.control.updateValueAndValidity(this.control);
    }
  }

  validate(_control:AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    this.control = _control;
    return this.valFn(_control);
  }
}
```

It works. `Validate` is called on initialization so I just store its parameter.
It is fuckin' ugly but it works.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get the control in a directive for a different purpose. I scoured high and low, and tried multiple things. This should work for me, though not ideal. Let me know if you ever dig anything more up on this.

Answer (score 0):

To get your hands on the abstractControl of the input you can do something like this:

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: 'input[type=date][maxDate]'
})
export class InputFullWithDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {
  constructor(@Self() private control: NgControl) {}
  /** the rest is mostly unchanged from the question */
}
```